# Removing overlapping areas

Tags: qgis

I have two maps, one with critically endangered mammals and one of current *strict nature reserves*. As a small part of a project I want to have a map showing the areas with critically endangered mammals that fall outside *strict nature reserves*. Below, the red shows areas with critically endangered mammals present, and the green areas are areas of strict nature reserves.

[image]

I made a new layer of the overlapping areas, which is the blue below. Now I want a layer that will show areas with critically endangered mammals present (the red), without the areas that are covered by the blue. How do I ''crop''these areas out of the layer? I already tried with the ''Select by location'' tool to remove areas that overlap, but that does not do a single thing. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Difference](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=difference#difference):

> Extracts features from the input layer that don’t fall within the
> boundaries of the overlay layer.

Comment: Thank you. But that doesn't seem possible, because the blue layer only covers small parts of a single feature of the red layer.